# cheating student VS. student cheating

Tags: adjectives

We found some students cheating.

We found some cheating students.

It would be appreciated, if someone please show me if there is any difference semantically between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We found some students cheating.

What we found was *students [in the act of] cheating*. We simply describe an action they we observed by a subject at the time that we found them, it does not mean we assume that cheating is what they always do. A similar sentence would be:

> We found some students taking an exam.
>   I saw a man driving a car.

A more general observation would be:

> We found some cheating students.

These students are the cheating kind of students. Maybe they were not actually cheating the moment we found them, but in general, we describe them as cheating students. A similar sentence would be:

> We found some intelligent students.
>   I saw a red apple.

Comment: Great answer! It was very useful for me, thank you very much.